# Could an attacker simply modify data that is sent along with the hash for the modified data?

Tags: security, hash, integrity

I tried searching on Google for something touching on this but I couldn't find anything.

Couldn't an attacker just send along the hash of their modified data to the receiver?  I assume that the receiver would just run the hash through the algorithm, and since the hash matches the data (albeit the modified data), the receiver would just go ahead and say "Okay, this data has been unmodified".
I suppose that hashing is a lot more complicated than this, but it was just a question that's been in my mind since I started learning about hashing, and I would like to address it.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hash-function-and-a-cryptographic-hash-function

Comment: If you can find a security protocol that actually works that way then yes, the attacker could do this. Hashing is not more complicated than that but real security protocols/systems are.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk That helps a lot. Appreciate the response.

Comment: As you suspect, sending just a hash is insufficient. The thing you're looking for is called a MAC (Message Authentication Code). It's based on a cryptographic hash, but as noted in previous comments, it's more than just that.